# MySQL select entries from last hour based on epoch field

Tags: mysql

I need to return all the entries in a MySQL database from the last hour. The database has a column named `time` that has epoch values in.

This bit of psuedo code is what I want to be able to achieve but am not sure how to do this in MySQL. In another language I'd check to see that the epoch value of `time` in each row is no more than 3,600 different.

```
SELECT * FROM dailyltc WHERE `time` <= 1 hour
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not using functions to convert your stored epoch value enables MySQL the use of an index. Because of that I prefer the calculate the limits with [UNIX_TIMESTAMP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) instead of converting the stored value to a DATETIME value.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    dailyltc
WHERE
    `time` >  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR);
```

Should newer values exist then you can simply add the upper bound:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    dailyltc
WHERE
    `time` >  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
AND
    `time` <=  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW());
```